# WPF: Creating a "DoubleBox" derived from a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to have a WPF control similar to a `TextBox` but with additional functionality to ensure that only numbers within a certain range are accepted. I came up with the following `DoubleBox` control:

```
public class DoubleBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Min), typeof(double), typeof(DoubleBox), new PropertyMetadata(double.NegativeInfinity, OnMinPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Max), typeof(double), typeof(DoubleBox), new PropertyMetadata(double.PositiveInfinity, OnMaxPropertyChanged));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Value), typeof(double), typeof(DoubleBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(double), OnValuePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnMinPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double min = (double)e.NewValue;
        double max = (double)d.GetValue(MaxProperty);
        double value = (double)d.GetValue(ValueProperty);

        if (min > max) throw new Exception("Min value is greater than max value.");

        if (value < min) d.SetValue(ValueProperty, min);
    }
    private static void OnMaxPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double min = (double)d.GetValue(MinProperty);
        double max = (double)e.NewValue;
        double value = (double)d.GetValue(ValueProperty);

        if (max < min) throw new Exception("Max value is less than min value.");

        if (value > max) d.SetValue(ValueProperty, max);
    }
    private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double min = (double)d.GetValue(MinProperty);
        double max = (double)d.GetValue(MaxProperty);
        double value = (double)e.NewValue;

        if (value < min) d.SetValue(ValueProperty, min);
        if (value > max) d.SetValue(ValueProperty, max);
    }

    public double Min
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MinProperty);
        set => SetValue(MinProperty, value);
    }
    public double Max
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(MaxProperty);
        set => SetValue(MaxProperty, value);
    }
    public double Value
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
            Text = Value.ToString();
        }
    }

    private double previousValue = 0.0;

    //protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    //{
    //  Text = Value.ToString();
    //  base.OnInitialized(e);
    //}
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double.TryParse(Text, out previousValue);
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(Text, out double currentValue))
        {
            if (currentValue < Min) currentValue = Min;
            if (currentValue > Max) currentValue = Max;
            Value = currentValue;
        }
        else Value = previousValue;

        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

}
```

Which can be used in the View like so:

```
<DoubleBox Min="{Binding Path=DoubleWithValueOf1, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{Binding Path=DoubleWithValueOf5, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

My first question is: Since I am not used to MVVM, is this overall approach correct? It seems that I am writing way too much code for such a simple thing.

My main question is: even though I am binding the `Value` property of the `DoubleBox`, the initial `Text` shown is `null` when I fire up the App, while I was expecting to see the `Value` as a `string`. I can "fix" this by overriding the `OnInitialized` method (commented above), but this doesn't seem correct and I lose the ability to see the real-time binding in the xaml designer on Visual Studio.

Comment: As a note, MVVM is not relevant when you write a control class.

Comment: Having a look at the source code of other similar controls that just accept numeric textual input, you'll be surprised how many lines of source code and markup you'll needed to get a functional, robust, implementation for such a "simple thing" :)
E.g. Xceed has some numeric controls at GitHub...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your implementation is wrong:

```
public double Value
{
    get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        Text = Value.ToString(); // here
    }
}
```

because there must not be anything else than SetValue in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The setter is not always called when the property is set, e.g. by a Binding. WPF may directly call SetValue instead.

Move the `Text` property assignment to the PropertyChanged callback, and also add a CoerceValueCallback instead of performing the range check in the PropertyChanged callback.

```
public double Value
{
    get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
    set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Value),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(DoubleBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            OnValuePropertyChanged, CoerceValueProperty));

private static object CoerceValueProperty(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    var db = (DoubleBox)d;
    var val = (double)value;
    return val < db.Min ? db.Min : val > db.Max ? db.Max : val;
}

private static void OnValuePropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var db = (DoubleBox)d;
    db.Text = db.Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess for consistency I would also create a ``CoerceMinProperty`` and ``CoerceMaxProperty`` and I would check for the ``Exception``s inside these methods. Then the ``OnMinPropertyChanged`` and ``OnMaxPropertyChanged`` methods would just update the ``Value`` directly if  needed (i.e., if it is outside the new range).

Comment: Yes, exactly. That would just have been too much code for the answer.

Comment: I would say I cannot use ValidateValueCallback since to validate min I also need to know the value of max (and vice-versa). It seems that inside the static method I only have access to the one corresponding property.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I am totally agree with Clemens's implement
and For your first questions answer is :
Yes as far your implementing control and its fine if you create custom control for modifying existing WPF control and this is not a MVVM part at all as its not relevant.
*This is a UI part.*

If you dont want to use this control in any othwe window/page then its fine if you write all logic via TextBox event handling.